# Как узнать, провел ли пользователь оплату на сайте?

Tags: python, django

На сайте используется система оплаты [Fondy](https://fondy.ru/). Как сделать проверку в шаблонах, провел ли пользователь оплату?(например, показать первые несколько объектов страницы, если пользователь не провел платеж или давать доступ к определенным страницам только после оплаты)

Код, который [предоставляет](https://github.com/cloudipsp/python-sdk) Fondy:

```
api = Api(merchant_id=, secret_key='')

checkout = Checkout(api=api)

data = {

    "currency": "RUB",

    "amount": 100,

    "order_desc": "Описание платежа",

    "order_id": str(time.time())

}

url = checkout.url(data).get('checkout_url')
```

Что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: в https://github.com/cloudipsp/python-sdk/blob/master/cloudipsp/order.py есть метод status.  если ему передать data, то будет возвращен статус этого платежа. Ну а дальше уже Вам решать. Кстати, `"order_id": str(time.time())` - не очень хороший способ. Подумайте о более надежном order_id, также это order_id желательно хранить где то в базе.

Comment: Получается, получив статус платежа как "оплачено", то можно делать задуманное. Но подскажите, пожалуйста, как его получить(как передать data к status)?

Comment: то есть, как вызвать функцию? а data - да вот она у Вас прям в вопросе.

Comment: Понятно про data, как её к status передать? Что вообще нужно сделать для получения статуса?

Comment: посмотрите в их тесты - https://github.com/cloudipsp/python-sdk/blob/master/tests/order_tests.py - Вам нужно создать объект Order и у него вызвать нужную функцию (если я все правильно понимаю).

Comment: исправил код - вот так:
    `api = Api(merchant_id=, secret_key='')
    order = Order(api=api)
    data = order.status({
        "currency": "RUB",
        "amount": 100,
        "order_desc": "Описание платежа",  
        "order_id": str(time.time())
    })
    url = order.url(data).get('checkout_url')`

Но вызывает ошибку о неверном заполнении. Почему?

Comment: Подумайте, что возвращает time.time(). А потом представьте себя на месте платежной системы

Comment: Почему time.time() может вызывать ошибку? Попробовал сделать вывод только натуральных чисел - не помогло. Вообще, DEBUG указывает на эту строку: 
**data = order.status({**

В чем же ошибка?

Comment: Потому что это order_id. До одного и того же заказа он должен быть одинаковый. А так Вы запрашиваете постоянно статус случайных новых заказов

Comment: Он должен быть одинаков для своих и уникален для других... Скажите, пожалуйста, как его тогда правильно прописать?

Comment: я об этом писал ещё в самом первом сообщении. При попытке оплаты, сгенерируйте id (да, это может быть текущее время, хотя это и не самый лучший id  - что, если два пользователя одновременно попробуют купить?) и сохраните его в свою базу. Все, теперь когда нужен будет id - просто возьмите его с базы.  Если нужно будет поменять алгоритм генерации id - ничего страшного, старых пользователей это не затронет (главное, их id не трогайте).